# ¿Como capturar los logs de una tarea gulp lanzada desde Node?

Tags: nodejs, sass, gulp, exec

Tengo una task en gulp para compilar sass como esta:

```
gulp.task('sass_pz', function(done) {
gulp.src('/source_scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({ }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("/compiled_css/"));
    done();
});
```

Que lanzo desde un script en node ejecutado por una interfaz web:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("gulp sass_pz");
```

El problema es capturar desde la aplicacion node los errores generados por sass para mostrarselos al usuario. Si ejecuto la tarea con `gulp sass_pz` me los muestra en el terminal, pero si la llamo desde node no lo hace.

Supongo que el quid de la cuestion está usando  `.pipe(sass({ }).on('error', sass.logError)` pero no se como mandar mensajes de gulp para ser recogidos por node.
¿como podria hacerlo? 
Gracias

Comment: Según la [documentación](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) el segundo parámetro de `exec` puede ser un callback, el cual recibe también en su segundo parámetro el `stdout` (standard output) por lo que podrías verlo así: `exec("gulp sass_pz", (err, stdout, stderr) => { !err && console.log(stdout); });`

Comment: Funcionando, gracias, si lo hubieras puesto como respuesta podria marcarla como correcta ;)